# Downloading of file is not happening in Curl with given url

Tags: c, curl, libcurl

While working with CURL(command line tool and library 
for transferring data with URLs) I am trying to download a file from a `url` like "`https://52.66.11.22/xyz/abc.txt`"

But is not downloading . but when i m giving "`http://52.66.11.22/xyz/abc.txt`", Its downloading.. for https i have given the certificate also. like below

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "cacert.pem")
```

I took log also , its giving the error like

```
curl_easy_perform() failed: SSL connect error<CR>
DOCURL::curl_retval=35,<CR>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should do like this:https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.html

open the ssl verify peer by `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1L);`

then call easy_perform should works.